# Why all the rank number become 1 when using a window function in a subquery

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

i have a table with traffic_id, date, start_time, session_id, page, platform, page-views, revenue, segment_id, and customer_id columns in my sessions table. Each customer_id could have multiple session_id with different revenue/date/start_time/page/platform/page_views/segment_id values. Sample data is shown below.

```
traffic_id|date|start_time|session_id|page|platform|page_views|revenue|segment_id|customer_id
303|1/1/2017|05:23:33|123457080|homepage|mobile|581|37.40|1|310559
```

I would like to know the max session revenue per customer and the session sequence number as the table shown below.

```
Customer_id|Date|Maximum|session_revenue|Session_id|Session_Sequence|       
 138858|1/13/17|100.44|123458749|5
```

I thought I could just use a subquery to do the job. But all the ranking values are 1 and session_id and date are wrong. Please help!---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
SELECT max(revenue),customer_id, date, session_id, session_sequence
FROM (
  SELECT
    revenue, 
    date, 
    customer_id,
    session_id,
    RANK() OVER(partition by customer_id ORDER BY date,start_time ASC) AS session_sequence
  FROM sessions
) AS a
group by customer_id
```

;

Comment: Help us help you - share your table structure and the query you used

Comment: The query I used is as below.-------------------------------------------------------------------------SELECT max(revenue),customer_id, date, session_id, session_sequence FROM ( SELECT revenue, date, customer_id, session_id, RANK() OVER(partition by customer_id ORDER BY date,start_time ASC) AS session_sequence FROM sessions ) AS a group by customer_id ;

Comment: The table structure is ----------------------------------------------------------------------------traffic_id - int|date - datetime|start_time - datetime|session_id - int|page－text|platform－text|page_views－int|revenue －double|segment_id－text|customer_id_int

Answer (score 0):

Your query should generate an error because the `GROUP BY` columns and `SELECT` columns are inconsistent.

Presumably you want the maximum revenue and the sequence number where that occurs.

```
SELECT s.*
FROM (SELECT s.*,
             RANK() OVER (partition by customer_id ORDER BY date, start_time ASC) AS session_sequence,
             MAX(revenue) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id) as max_revenue
      FROM sessions
     ) s
WHERE revenue = max_revenue;
```